# The document at the url https://xxx.xxx was not recognized as a known document type

Tags: c#, .net, webservice

Actualmente quiero acceder a un webservice que me retorna un xml con cierta información que necesita y lo quiero añadir a una aplicación de consola ya que se ejecutar cada cierto tiempo.

Lo quiero añadir como referencia de servicio a mi aplicacion de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy click en el botón de GO con el webservice me sale le siguiente error:

```
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'.
  - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xxx.xxx'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://santecmxdes.service-now.com/api/now/table/cost_plan?sysparm_display_value=TRUE.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Comment: si pones la url en el browser puedes visualizar la pagina por defecto del servicio WCF? recuerda que la url debe terminar en .svc

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si me aparece informacion en el browser, pero es un webservice de service now no .asmx y retorna un xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se trata de un servicio `asmx` no se utiliza el `Service Reference` tienes que usar el `Web Reference`

Para esto tiene que usar el boton `Advanced..`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es necesario porque el proxy que se genera para estos servicio es diferente, recuerda que para un `asmx` se usa el `wsdl.exe` mientras que para un servicio de `wcf` se usa el `Svcutil.exe`